# What are the educational qualifications of Bruce Banner in the movie The Incredible Hulk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, marvel, the-incredible-hulk-2008

In the move *The Hulk* (2003) Bruce’s credentials were seen in a newspaper cutting David Banner preserved, and were:

1. Bruce graduated from MIT in 1999 completing his Bachelors degree
2. Bruce did his Masters in Science at the University of California (2001)
3. Doctorate from Berkeley Nuclear Institute of Biotechnology (this I am assuming because he works for the University lab there on a specialized subject)

But in *The Incredible Hulk* (2008), all I remember seeing of his educational credentials is:

1. in a conversation with Betty he reminds her of their volunteering for induced hallucinations at Harvard University, so did he graduate from Harvard
2. he was working at the Culver University, VA.

Does he have a PHD from the University there, and what are his educational credentials overall?

Comment: Given your clear interest in the 2003 Hulk movie (based on the number questions you've asked) you might consider becoming ***the*** subject expert; reading all the interviews and articles, novelisation and making - of documentaries, etc...

Comment: Volunteering as a participant in a study at a university does not necessarily mean he graduated from the university.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand that the the Hulk film from 2003 and The Incredible Hulk do not share the same continuity. The Incredible hulk takes place in the MCU, but the 2003 Hulk film does not.

While the best answer the MCU Wiki can provide is that he "specialized" in nuclear physics and biochemistry, he is repeatedly referred to as "DOCTOR Banner" in the first Avengers film. I'd surmise that he received a doctorate in biochemistry, given that his studies mostly seemed to be focused on biochemistry issues (being a part of the Bioscience Department at Culver)

[image]